# How to Replace an Angular Attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I replace an Angular attribute that already has a value in it? For example:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('edit', function(){
  return {
    template: '<a ng-href="{{data}}">Link Text</a>',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elm, attr){
      scope.data = 'http://www.example.com';
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<a edit ng-href="test"></a>
```

That just appends the link url to the "test" href. I tried using

```
elm.attr('ng-href', '{{data}}');
```

and many variations on that idea, but it didn't work.

Comment: are you asking this for any directive or specially for ngHref?

Comment: Can you show this in a plunkr and explain in the comments what you see vs what you expect... also explaining the higher level goal might help to get a better solution since there are various ways to define directives or organize things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `compile` function in directive, and redeclare this attribute in it:

```
.directive('edit', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
   return {
      template: '<a ng-href="{{data}}">Link Text</a>',
      replace: true,
      restrict:'A',
      compile:function(elm, attr){
        return {
          pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { 
             iAttrs.ngHref = "{{data}}";
          },
          post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            scope.data = 'http://www.example.com';
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }])
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lBA9xR1VbWHqHbc5KG7w?p=preview